# Can I set a TTL for @Cacheable EhCache per entry?

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache, spring-cache

I need to set TTL per cache entry. I use EhCache, Spring Cache.
EhCache does not provide an API to supply a TTL for a put method.
An alternative way would be to create multiple caches with different TTLs, but then I would need to select cache at runtime. I looked at extending CacheInterceptor, but could not find code where they select cache based on cache name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Spring's Cache Abstraction has been very clearly [documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/6.1/integration/cache/specific-config.html) on matters concerning expiration and eviction policies. Spring's [Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/6.1/integration/cache/strategies.html) is a framework for handling caching concerns in your application(s) uniformly across many different caching providers.

The implementation of expiration, whether TTL (Time-To-Live) or TTI (Time-To-Idle), along with eviction, or simply other capabilities (e.g. persistence) of a caching provider in general, can vary greatly, and are therefore best handled by the caching provider itself, especially when you consider distributed or client/server topologies.

Ideally, you should use a caching provider capable of handling your caching needs, particularly with (TTL) expiration.

Redis is a good alternative. Spring Data Redis can plugin Redis as a caching provider to Spring's Cache Abstraction. See [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/3.2.0-M2/reference/html/#redis:support:cache-abstraction:expiration) on expiration. Depending on the configuration, this is backed by Redis' [`GETEX` command](https://redis.io/commands/getex/) (and `SET(EX)` on cache.put(key, value)`).

Are you certain you cannot accomplish what you need with EhCache's "[Custom expiry](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.7/expiry.html#custom-expiry)" support? This is often the case.

Comment: I don't see how EhCache's custom expiry could be applied to a cache entry.

Comment: Not in the same way that Redis's `GETEX` (and `SETEX`) commands do. Rather, _EhCache_ does so uniformly across all cache entries in a specific cache, which is very similar to how most caching providers handle expiration (whether TTL or TTI). Typically, cache entries in a particular cache (e.g. HTTP Sessions) all expire at the same rate (e.g. 5 minutes of inactivity). It is usually uncommon for individual entries to have varying expiration policies. For that, you need to apply a caching provider (like Redis) to handle this UC. It is atypical. Spring is not going to help OOTB.

Comment: If I may ask, why do you need individual entries in the same cache to expire at different rates? What is your UC?